# redis-py connection refused

Tags: python, docker, redis, redis-py

I have this code in Python:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host="redis-db", password="foobared")
r.get("some-key")
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 611, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 612, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 677, in _connect
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 665, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1705, in get
    return self.execute_command("GET", name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1235, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1387, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 617, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to redis-db:6379. Connection refused.
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7
    container_name: redis-db
    volumes:      # I set my password in the conf file
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.0.6
    depends_on:
      - app
```

And I have another SEPARATE docker-compose.yml file in another directory (Don't ask me why I separated these):

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: socketio-sv
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - some_app_net
    tty: true

networks:
  some_app_net:
    external: true
```

Then, I used `docker network inspect app_net` to check both redis and socketio containers are in the same network:

```
 "Containers": {
            "415933ecbc99a05d28c35e34c183c860c7d96572e1b4d9473f0d7352fdaf8e29": {
                "Name": "redis-db",
                "EndpointID": "538c288d0292acfa7c6245a94ee5016a4568d10acf0bc818d23a758bc799cb47",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:0a:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "10.10.0.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "dd1e4a70b0825bea8d1793d7f25cb95a41637c1424824627fff78df54a36af35": {
                "Name": "socketio-sv",
                "EndpointID": "0cb6f118226c4e22c45670fdc88be7dc2eec9e90e6e77271e64166016c19f4d4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:0a:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.10.0.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

And as you can see, the both redis and socketio servers are in the same network.

I am not sure why this error happened. The password and the hostname are right, and I also exposed the right port.

Comment: Your output shows that they have IP addresses from the same subnet. It does not show that they are in the same network. You should combine every in one file and docker-compose will create one network without any special configuration.

Comment: @Klaus D. So, should I put both socketio and redis container definitions in one docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: I note that you're getting a "connection refused" error, which implies that the host name `redis-db` is resolving, which in turn implies that both containers are in fact on the same Docker network.  Can you connect to Redis from other contexts?  (In your Redis configuration, have you set it to `bind 0.0.0.0`?)

Comment: Oh, I did not set it to `0.0.0.0`. Maybe changing it might solve the problem.